# How to align multiple authors properly in report class?

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles, report

How can one align multiple authors without the need of using additional packages such as `authblck`? Can this be done by altering `\@author`?

Take for example the following working examples:

## **MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{My MWE}
\author{This~is~my~Name \and This~is~my~author \and My~other~coauthor \and My~Last coauthor}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The output is (where the wrong aligment can be slightly seen, see the last author alignment with respect to the others):

[image: FirstOutput]

If one of the first three names is longer, the wrong alignment is more evident:

[image: SecondOuput]

## EDIT:

**Important note:** The solution must be transparent to the person making a document, I am in sort of the creation of my own class, the user of the class will still use something like `\author{This~is~my~Name \and This~is~my~author \and My~other~coauthor \and My~Last coauthor}`.

Comment: You cannot expect an simple solution for a non-simple case. LaTeX has boundaries, which need to be tackled by hand. Titles are the things that need the most attention.

Comment: You could fix the column witdh from the start, but i bet this will look ugly as well in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `tabular` in the author macro:

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{My MWE}
\author{\begin{tabular}{cc}This~is~my~LongName & This~is~my~author\\My~other~coauthor & My~Last coauthor\\\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Marjin I like this answer, thank you so much for taking the time. However, I am planning on sort of create my own class, I would like this to be transparent to the user, I mean, the user will provide a line like `\author{me \and my friend \and alli}`, your solution isn't transparent, I upvoted you, but I'll modify my question to insert this as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}

\title{My MWE}
\author{%
  This is my Name\\ 
  My other coauthor 
\and 
  This is my author\\ 
  My Last coauthor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am in the process of creating sort of my own class, I upvoted your answer, but the idea is the solution should be transparent to the user, the user shall do something like `\author{me \and my friend \and alli}`, your solution is not transparent as it requires the user to specifically create the "columns" of the table.